# Is it possible to compute many2many field values without storing them?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to create a *virtual* `Many2many` field for informational purpose only. Is it possible to compute and populate `Many2many` field without storing the generated *virtual* records?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to create Virtual Many2many field for informational purpose. Please see the below sample code,

```
@api.one
@api.depends(
    'move_id.line_id.account_id',
    'move_id.line_id.reconcile_id.line_id',
    'move_id.line_id.reconcile_partial_id.line_partial_ids',
)
def _compute_move_lines(self):
    # Give Journal Items related to the payment reconciled to this invoice.
    # Return partial and total payments related to the selected invoice.
    self.move_lines = self.env['account.move.line']
    if not self.move_id:
        return
    data_lines = self.move_id.line_id.filtered(lambda l: l.account_id == self.account_id)
    partial_lines = self.env['account.move.line']
    for data_line in data_lines:
        if data_line.reconcile_id:
            lines = data_line.reconcile_id.line_id
        elif data_line.reconcile_partial_id:
            lines = data_line.reconcile_partial_id.line_partial_ids
        else:
            lines = self.env['account.move.line']
        partial_lines += data_line
        self.move_lines = lines - partial_lines

move_lines = fields.Many2many('account.move.line', string='Entry Lines',
    compute='_compute_move_lines')
```

You can see above example in **/addons/account/account_invoice.py** file in the odoo addons.